# WinRT ListView virtualization

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to display 10k items in list view from database.
I tried to use visualization using `IList` interface.
Idea was to fetch items one by one, as requested by listview. (Only visible items).
But getting following exception when I create `VirtualComboList` object and assign it to ListView.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Similar code works fine for WP8(Silverlight).
Now, can anybody tell what am I missing?

```
public void initializeList()
{
    int ItemsCount = getItemsCountFromDatabase();
    VirtualComboList list = new VirtualComboList(ItemsCount);
    listBox1.ItemsSource = list; //Exception at this line
}
```

My VirtualComboList class implementing IList interface

```
class VirtualComboList : IList<string> 
        {
            int ItemCount;

            public VirtualComboList(int count)
            {
                ItemCount = count;
            }

            public int IndexOf(string item)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            public void Insert(int index, string item)
            {

            }

            public void RemoveAt(int index)
            {

            }

            public string this[int index]
            {
                get
                {
                    return getStringFromDatabaseForIndex(index);
                }
                set
                {

                }
            }

            public void Add(string item)
            {

            }

            public void Clear()
            {

            }

            public bool Contains(string item)
            {
                return false;
            }

            public void CopyTo(string[] array, int arrayIndex)
            {

            }

            public int Count
            {
                get { return ItemCount; }
            }

            public bool IsReadOnly
            {
                get  { return true ; }
            }

            public bool Remove(string item)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return null;
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `GetEnumerator` methods return `null`. Don't do that. The `ItemsControl` (`ListView` in this case) is trying to iterate over the list using the `Enumerator`, which is `null`, causing the exception.

You should look into a proper implementation of `GetEnumerator`. Or, you can have a `List<string>` as a field/property of your custom class and simply expose the methods of the underlying collection so that you don't have to implement any of them yourself.

Comment: Yes, GetEnumerator should not return null, my fault.